# Printf interfering with I2C module value reading

Tags: c, printf, embedded-linux, i2c

There's a device which has an i2c temperature module that reads the temperature of the processor. We read the temperature value from i2c and then present it to the user. There's this `printf` inside a function that is completely irrelevant of the i2c processes. This is the function:

```
endProcessFunction(int dummy){
    printf("App_host: Error Handler Started!!");

    App_sendEvent(APP_CMD_ERROR_COND);

    sleep(1);

    sendIpcMsg(some_signal,2,some_thread);

    appEndState = 1;
    syncRunning = 0;
    distRecRunning = 0;
    sem_post(&distRecSem);

    App_sendEvent(APP_CMD_APPHOST_FAIL);
}
```

Now, when we delete one exclamation mark from the end of this `printf` the value read from the i2c is normal (around 35 centigrade degrees) but if we compile and run with two exclamation marks, the i2c will always read FFFF (16 bit integer max value).

I'm not sure what's going on but we've tried,

- Disabling some `printf` calls from other functions (suspected heap size problem)
- Putting a `"\n"` at the end of the `string` to make sure it's closed
- Other stuff that we thought wouldn't work and didn't (like moving the `printf` call around in the function, putting it in the middle etc.)

To be absolutely clear, this function will stop the infinite loops other threads are in and end the main thread after that. So, it's only ever called when the program has encountered a problem it cannot recover from. If this function was called we wouldn't be able to see the value readings from the i2c anyway.

Also, yeah, we technically do not encounter this problem, but this isn't a fix, it's a hackjob. So I'm looking for an actual solution.

Could this still be a heap size problem (even though we removed other printf calls in the program)? Anything else we could try to make this work with a longer string size?

Answer (score 0):

This possibly could be timing issue and is partly because of different I2C hardware implementations on different platforms. In addition to possible software bugs, you should also be aware that I2C masters and slaves must respond in a timely way and it looks like a little delay introduced by printf() is causing sync issues. It happens when the other end does not respond fast enough. Delay caused by printf() could lead to aborted messages or incorrect data. Reading a value of 0xFFFF is something you typically get when the slave does not respond, the bus will float to high when the slave does not send anything. You should be able to detect some of the problems by checking the return status of the actual read() operation at a low level and possibly with the oscilloscope or logic analyzer.

Comment: This does make sense, but the `printf()` function there never (except when the program is shutting down) gets used. So, it shouldn't really introduce any delay to the program.